# Find the probability of $P(t<X_1<X_2)$ where $X_i\sim \exp(\rho_i)$ and independent from each other.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

Let $X_i\sim \exp(\rho_i)$ independent from each other.

How can I show that the following hold,

$P(t<X_1<X_2)=\int_t^\infty P(x<X_2)f_{X1}(x)dx=\frac{\rho_1}{\rho_1+\rho_2}e^{-(\rho_1+\rho_2)t} $

Comment: Hint: show your efforts. See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$X_i\sim exp(\rho_i)$, $\rho_i>0$, so $X_i$ has density $f_{X_i}(x)=
\rho_i e^{-\rho_i x}$ for $x>0$ and zero otherwise.

Hence, the cdf is ${\bf P}(X_i\leq x)=F_{X_i}(x)=\int_0^x f_{X_i}(t)dt = 
\int_0^x \rho_i e^{-\rho_i t}dt = 1- e^{-\rho_i x}$ for $x>0$ and zero otherwise.

Now,
\begin{eqnarray*}
{\bf P}(t<X_1<X_2) &=&
\int_0^{\infty}{\bf P}(t<X_1<X_2|X_1=x)f_{X_1}(x)dx\\
&=&
\int_0^{\infty}{\bf P}(t<x<X_2|X_1=x)f_{X_1}(x)dx\\ 
&=&
\int_0^{\infty}{\bf P}(t<x<X_2)f_{X_1}(x)dx\\ 
&=&
\int_t^{\infty}{\bf P}(t<x<X_2)f_{X_1}(x)dx\\ 
&=&
\int_t^{\infty}{\bf P}(x<X_2)f_{X_1}(x)dx\\
&=&
\int_t^{\infty}e^{-\rho_2 x}\rho_1e^{-\rho_1 x}dx\\
&=&
\rho_1\int_t^{\infty}e^{-(\rho_1+\rho_2) x}dx\\
&=&
\rho_1  \frac{e^{-(\rho_1+\rho_2) x}}{-(\rho_1+\rho_2)}\Big|_t^{\infty}\\
&=&
\frac{\rho_1}{\rho_1+\rho_2} e^{-(\rho_1+\rho_2) t}\\
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: how do we know that the first equality is true?

Comment: By the Law of Total Probability. :)

Comment: See https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter5/5_2_3_conditioning_independence.php